# Combining ranges/arrays to feed into IRR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, irr

I want to use the `IRR` function in Excel; however, my inputs exists in a non-contiguous range.

For example, I want to know the return of an asset over time (each row is a time period).

1. Column A has the cost (cash outflow) of owning the asset/
2. Column B is the price of the asset (cash inflow if liquidated).

   - So `A1` is cost of owning the asset at time 1, `A2`
     is the cost of owning at time 2 etc.
   - `B1` is the liquidation price of the asset at time 1, B2 is the liquidation price of the asset at time 2 etc.
   - In Column C, I would like the return for each time period if I liquidate.

So for example `C6` is the return of the asset if I liquidate at period 6, `C7` is the return of the asset if I liquidate at period 7 etc.  So for `C6`, the cash outflow would be `A1:A5`, the cash inflow would be `B6`.

How do I feed IRR these two inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a technique I saw [lori_m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252820/lori-m) use

```
=IRR(IF(1-FREQUENCY(9^9,A1:A5),A1:A5,B6))
```

As per the simple example below, the `FREQUENCY`formula is used to mesh together `A1:A5`with `B6`. Returning an identical `ÌRR`to the same cashflows in a continuous range

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what this is doing?

Comment: @agrimpathak Why would you downvote a working answer I took the time to create for your question?

Comment: I don't see how this will work, but still I tried and played around with it, and it didn't work.  And is this suppose to be an array formula?  Also, I think the answer will benefit with a brief explanation.

Comment: It isn't an array formula. It worked as is when I tried it on the same data layout you described.

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed it works and accepted it.  Though conceptually, how is FREQUENCY combining A1:A5 and B6?

Comment: Its a little complex ..... `FREQUENCY` is used to look up a very high number against 5 bins (A1:A5) which then returns 5 zeroes (as the data doesnt fit in these bins) and a single 1 (FREQUENCY returns an extra element. So the `IF` part then reads 1-{0,0,0,0,0,1} which then gives five TRUE results (A1:A5) and then 1 FALSE (B6) in a single array of values.